# cakephp admin prefix assets

Tags: php, cakephp

I want have cakephp app with 2 part the main site and the admin panel and layout and design of the 2 part are seprate

I created **Admin** prefix and put my admins controller and template file in **Admin** folder

I created a folder in webroot named **Admin** too and put my admin related assets there .

In cakephp **config/App.php** there is part to specify base url of assets . i's look like this

```
'App' => [
    'namespace' => 'App',
    'encoding' => env('APP_ENCODING', 'UTF-8'),
    'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US'),
    'base' => false,
    'dir' => 'src',
    'webroot' => 'webroot',
    'wwwRoot' => WWW_ROOT,
    // 'baseUrl' => env('SCRIPT_NAME'),
    'fullBaseUrl' => false,
    'imageBaseUrl' => '',
    'cssBaseUrl' => 'css/',
    'jsBaseUrl' => 'js/',
    'paths' => [
        'plugins' => [ROOT . DS . 'plugins' . DS],
        'templates' => [APP . 'Template' . DS],
        'locales' => [APP . 'Locale' . DS],
    ],
],
```

I'm wondering how can i specify defferent dicrectory for assets for **Admin** ?

Or how should i call css method in Html helper for admin ?

I load css file in main part of site like this

```
<?= $this->Html->css('custom.css') ?>
```

But i have to load it for admin side like this

```
<?= $this->Html->css('../Admin/css/custom.css') ?>
```

Is there any way i can fix this and load it like i do the main part ?

I also used it like this but it seems not to recognize prefix option

```
<?= $this->Html->css('custom.css' , ['prefix'=>'Admin']) ?>
```

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Comment: this article is about prefix routing . my question is about load css files with Html helper not links. any idea how to do that ? @Alimon-Karim

Comment: Did you keep your view layout files in src/Template/Admin ? So your Layout folder in your Template folder and it is not in your src/Template/Admin folder, if your folder is look like this then you don't need anything to do in your layout folder. 
<?= $this->Html->css('custom.css') ?> this line will work perfectly.